# Laravel change img src on data fetch

Tags: laravel

I am retrieving text which contains images saved in WYSIWYG editor(Summernote). Is there a way to replace `src` attribute value in `img` tags using `asset()`?

Example:

```
<img src="images/image.jpg"/>...
```

To:

```
<img src="https://.../images.jpg"/>
```

I want solution which would cover all bases: spaces in image name, different extensions...

Comment: @AlImrunShowrov yes

Comment: It's the same I showed in example

Comment: I am getting full html code

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use the curly brace syntax in your blade to render the `asset()`

```
<img src="{{ asset('whatever_you_want') }}"/>
```

Comment: I am getting full html text, as I said coming from text edittor

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in Blade. You could, in your model, add a function that replaces all images to full paths. This could be done through a regex pattern that looks for URLs in  tags.

I would, however, make sure the full path to the image is included in the text in the database. This way, you always have access to the right path to the image, and you're not relying on a piece of code to display the right image.

Comment: I am actually trying to do it in model, so I could use it in API calls